# Adding About box to Android App in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to add an About Box to an App in an Android App using Eclipse. I was told I need to use a menu option to bring it up. It's just a simple affair where after pressing a menu button, a small box comes up with the name, version, and a logo. I'm using API 2.2 (Froyo), but I can't seem to figure out how to make the box appear.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about using a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? You should look into the AlertDialog and related builder classes.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything because I have no idea what to do in regards to something like that. It's a little beyond my education level this month. Not sure how to proceed and looking into this new stuff and programatically building a Dialog is something I've never done before.